# GET in for loop needs to be faster (httr) in R

Tags: r, loops, get, try-catch, httr

I need to write a R script which sends at the end a huge amount of get requests to a server. Each row of my data frame contains several information. The final column "url" builds http requests in each row - for example: https://logsxxx.xxx.com/xx.xx?.....

It may happen that I must send 300.000 - 1.000.000 get request with the script.
The good thing is that my script works and the requests reaches the server.
The bad thing is that the loop costs a lot of time until all rows are send. It takes about 9 hours for 300.000 rows.

I've tested if its possible with ifelse or apply but I failed...

```
system.time(
for (i in 1:300000){
    try(
      {
      GET(mydata$url[i], timeout(3600))
      print(paste("row",i,"sent at",Sys.time()))
      }
    , silent=FALSE)
}
)
```

Another bad thing is that the script may fails to send 100% if the internet connection breaks for any reason. Then I can see the following error:

```
[1] "row 18 sent at 2019-01-18 14:22:05"
[1] "row 19 sent at 2019-01-18 14:22:06"
[1] "row 20 sent at 2019-01-18 14:22:06"
[1] "row 21 sent at 2019-01-18 14:22:06"
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
[1] "row 23 sent at 2019-01-18 14:22:16"
[1] "row 24 sent at 2019-01-18 14:22:16"
[1] "row 25 sent at 2019-01-18 14:22:16"
```

At least the script doesn't break completely and goes on with the next row. The problem is here that the longer the internet connection fails the more rows would not send.

I would be very grateful if:

- someone could show me a faster way to send the requests - maybe without the nested for loop
- and show me how I can do something like this with the code: "if the get request fails because of internet connection, retry 3 times before going to the next get request. Do that until all elements of i are send"

Kind regards,

Comment: The most important thing here is to log. Log to a file every request and its status, in such a way you can retry the failed attempts. For the speed part, you could send multiple requests at a time in parallel. See here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/ to get an idea on how to go in parallel with R.

Comment: Hello I tried to use apply as nested for loops are not really recommended in terms of speed but it seems that I run into another problem: hits<-subset(mydata,select=c(23)) try({
    apply(hits, 1, function(x) GET(hits, timeout(3600)))
    print(paste("row",i,"sent at",Sys.time()))
  }, silent=FALSE) Error : cannot allocate vector of size 851.5 Mb